# Jq: testing a field during walk

Tags: json, key, traversal, jq

Consider following jq config:

```
walk 
( 
  if (type == "object" and .key | test("something")) then 
    del(.) 
  else 
    . 
  end
)
```

And following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "something",
    "value": "something"
  },
  {
    "key": "another thing",
    "value": "another thing"
  },
  {
    "key": "something",
    "value": "something"
  }
]
```

However, jq throws following error:

> jq: error (at :13): boolean (false) cannot be matched, as it is not a string

13 is the last line of the input. What boolean value is it trying to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `walk()` is not required here. I would use `map()` like this:

```
jq 'map(select(.key!="something"))'
```

---

About the error you reported, you miss parentheses. It should be:

```
jq 'walk(if(type == "object" and (.key | test("something"))) then del(.) else . end)'
                                 ^                        ^
```

Comment: I'm getting `jq: error  null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string` when trying to use this
If I change it to (.key = test("something")) I get `object ({"autoprefi...) cannot be matched, as it is not a string`

Comment: Well that depends on your input document. Go ahead and open a question

Answer (score 3):

1. As @hek2mgl explained, the answer to your question about the error message is that `(X and Y | Z)` is parsed as `(X and Y) | Z`.
2. The main problem with your query is the occurrence of `del(.)`.  The "." in this case refers to the object, and thus using del/1 here is simply wrong.  Since it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do, let me venture to guess that it is to delete the object (.) itself.  That can be done using `empty`:

```
walk(if type == "object" and (.key | test("something"))
     then empty
     else . end)
```

More robustly:

```
walk(if type == "object" and (.key | (type == "string" and test("something")))
     then empty
     else . end)
```

Comment: When I try to run the suggestion from 2. I get `jq: error (at test.json:76): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string`

Comment: My guess is that you need to add a test to check the object has the key. This can be done using has("key"). You might also want to check it's string-valued.